# 1D Finite element method: Function contineously differentiable?

Tags: integration, derivatives, finite-element-method

I m currently reading the book "The finite element method in electromagnetics" written by Jian-Ming Jin.

On page 50 and 51 which I attach as a screenshot below they show for an example functional, that minimizing the functional will lead to the solution of the pde in 3.12.

My question is: In the step 3.8 to 3.9 one did an integration by parts. For this step $\alpha \frac{d\phi}{dx}$ has to be differentiable? If I assume that $\alpha$ to be differentiable, then $\phi$ has to be differentiable twice.

When I minimize the functinal in practice I discretize space and assume in all discretized space intervals for example linear functions (linear element functions). With these linear functions I stick together my $\phi$. But this $\phi$ is then of course only contineous, but not twice differentiable!

Does anyone know a solution to this? Maybe it is okay if the discretization is fine enough?

Many thanks in advance.
[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: Yes, the idea is that in the limit of discretization the solution of the weak (variational) form approaches the solution to the strong (PDE) form.  There are many assumptions of course.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation where I can read about this in a little bit more detail? It seems that this book goes over these details without even mentioning them...

Comment: Are you coming to this from a theoretical or a computational mindset?

Comment: In the end I of course want to compute something, but at the moment I try to understand the mathematics.

Comment: There are many online resources. Try https://web.stanford.edu/class/energy281/FiniteElementMethod.pdf  There is the much more formal, such as https://folk.uio.no/kent-and/sommerskole/material/book_20april.pdf